# Saving video to azure, unable to load video some times

Tags: angularjs, azure, video

Hello all I am having the following code to save video to azure, which is working fine. But when I am loading the videos and trying to play them I am unable to play some of them. I am calling this using a service to execute for every 2 seconds to record the video from the angular service

```
public async Task<int> Save(System.IO.Stream stream, string name)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(memStream);
    memStream.Position = 0;
    // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureConfig.CONNECTION_STRING);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties = await blobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync();
        // Set the default service version to be used for anonymous requests.
     serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2016-05-31";
        // Set the service properties.
     await blobClient.SetServicePropertiesAsync(serviceProperties);
        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("video");
        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
    CloudAppendBlob appBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(name + ".webm");
    if (!await appBlob.ExistsAsync())
    {
        await appBlob.CreateOrReplaceAsync();
    }
    appBlob.Properties.ContentType = "video/webm;codecs=vp9";
    await appBlob.SetPropertiesAsync();

    appBlob.Metadata.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("uploadedDate", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

    await appBlob.AppendFromStreamAsync(memStream);

    return 0;
}
```

The video is getting uploaded but when I am trying to view the video some times the video is not getting displayed. I am using similar kind of this where for every 2 seconds I am calling a service to save the video in to azure

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `append` blob instead of `block` blob?

Comment: No, but I am not sure how can I do the same with block

Comment: I tried by bg y using block but not seeing the file getting saved in blob